# Rosdep errors on osx; cant find dependencies

Tags: rosdep, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just downloaded a vanilla ROS install for osx (desktop-full, electric), and my ultimate goal is to build the openni-kinect libraries.  Problems there aside, I seem to be encountering numerous errors within the rosdep dependency resolver.

Here is a simple test case:

```
$ rosdep install geometry
```

And the result:

```
Failed to find rosdep eigen for package tf_conversions on OS:osx version:lion
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install eigen
```

(Note: I am not able to build geometry either due to errors within the python-orocos-kdl package)

Errors similar to this with packages that need to be installed with macports are very prominent when I try to rosdep *anything*

Given that people have gotten this working on osx before, I can only conclude that I have done something wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27994/rosdep-errors-on-osx;-cant-find-dependencies/) by [sissow2](https://answers.ros.org/users/1820/sissow2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-20**:
Are you using homebrew or macports for your dependencies?

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-20**:
FYI ... I still haven't gotten the kinect libraries (openni) to work right. However, I have been very successful with the open source libfreenect.

**Comment by [sissow2](https://answers.ros.org/users/1820/sissow2/) on 2012-02-20**:
I am making some headway actually;  I have built (and used) openni before for an independent project.  It really doesn't want to play nicely with ROS though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try following the [homebrew](http://ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew) install instructions, you shouldn't have an issue.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sissow2](https://answers.ros.org/users/1820/sissow2/) on 2012-02-20**:
I want to, but I cant really switch from macports right now; I have too much built using it.